# Working tk canvas (drawing app with images) deletes objects from canvas

Tags: tkinter, tkinter-canvas

seeking answer and a possible solution to a curious unintended effect.

i'm making a drawing app that uses a .png image from disk to paint with on tk canvas.
read many threads on garbage collection and tk canvas but still none the wiser why this effect occurs.
all you need to replicate this is to have a 512 by 512 pixel wide image and place it where the following script is located and rename your image to "default.png" without quotation marks. also im running this on mac python 3.7.3 and have same effect on win 10 python 3.7.4

script uses PIL for resizing default.png and saving it as defaultworkbrush.png to same working directory then loads defaultworkbrush.png into a paint function that draws this image onto
the canvas like a normal drawing brush would. everything works as intended.
i also made a small function to resize the defaultworkbrush.png by right clicking once so
when u start drawing again u can see that the brush has changed and the paint function now draws with the new "shape". so far so good.

but as u just start to go nuts and draw on the canvas your masterpiece gets erased seemingly randomly quite fast, within like 20 seconds of continuous drawing.
expected result would be to be able to draw indefinitely and the program slowing down as canvas gets flooded with more objects and ram filling up. that's not what happens.

how do i fix this? what do i have to change to be able to just draw without the canvas deleting my objects? thanks in advance.

```py
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image

a1=Image.open('default.png').convert('RGB')
a2=a1.resize((180,180), Image.NEAREST)
brush='defaultworkbrush.png'
a2.save(brush)
a1.close()

def resizzle(event):
    a1=Image.open('defaultworkbrush.png')
    a2=a1.resize((300,100), Image.NEAREST)
    brush='defaultworkbrush.png'
    a2.save(brush)
    a1.close()

def motion(event):
    x,y=event.x,event.y
    return x,y

def paint(event):
    Ltk1=PhotoImage(file='defaultworkbrush.png')
    Ltk1.image=Ltk1
    he,ha=motion(event)
    cv.create_image((he, ha), image=Ltk1)
           
root=Tk()

cv=Canvas(root, width=1280, height=600)
cv.pack(expand=NO, fill=NONE, side=TOP)
cv.bind("<Button-3>",resizzle)
cv.bind("<Motion>",motion)
cv.bind("<B1-Motion>",paint)

global Ltk1
Ltk1=PhotoImage(file='defaultworkbrush.png')
Ltk1.image=Ltk1

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: `Ltk1.image=Ltk1` what do you indent to do here. People usually use this with widgets and not `PhotoImage` instance.

Comment: this was the only way i could keep a photoimage reference, i might be using it wrong, but uncommenting it makes the drawing to not show up on canvas. got idea from here:https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/photoimage.htm   quote "To avoid this, the program must keep an extra reference to the image object. A simple way to do this is to assign the image to a widget attribute, like this:

label = Label(image=photo)
label.image = photo # keep a reference!
label.pack() "

Comment: Thats why i said widget, its fine though, it could be anything like `Ltk1.imaasdasdadasdasdasdge=Ltk1`, its just done to keep reference, i believe